# Enviar fecha desde la vista a un input de type:date

Tags: c#, html, mvc

Necesito que en este campo me quede la fecha que le mando desde la vista de C#

[image: Ejemplo de como me aparece en el navegador en estos momentos]

Tengo en la vista de c# la siguiente linea de código, pero no me funciona:

```
<td>
    <label for="FechaVencimiento">Fecha Vencimiento:</label>
</td>
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Facturas.FechaVencimiento, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", @type = "Date", @required = 1, date = Model.Facturas.FechaVencimiento })
</td>
```

Que etiqueta debo utilizar en la vista de c# para mandarle la fecha correctamente y que me lo cargue en el navegador ?

Answer (score 2):

Muchas veces el `input` no reconoce el dato tipo `DateTime`, hay que formatearlo.

Intenta la siguiente línea:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Facturas.FechaVencimiento, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", @type = "Date", @required = 1, date = Model.Facturas.FechaVencimiento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })
```

Solo estoy añadiendo `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` para darle formato a la fecha

Answer (score 0):

Si `FechaVencimiento` es de tipo `DateTime` debería bastarte con hacer:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.Facturas.FechaVencimiento, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class= "form-control input-sm"}})
```